# How to combine multiple rows with multiple columns with headings in one table?

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I am struggling to create a table with three dimension to look up a fourth.

Consider the following binomial table as an example

```
##===##=================##===##
||   ||        p        ||   ||
|| n **-----+-----+-----** k ||
||   || .1  | .25 | .5  ||   ||
##===##=====*=====*=====##===##
||   || ... | ... | ... || 1 ||
||   **-----+-----+-----**---**
|| 3 || ... | ... | ... || 2 ||
||   **-----+-----+-----**---**
||   || ... | ... | ... || 3 ||
##===##=====*=====*==========##
||   || ... | ... | ... || 1 ||
||   **-----+-----+-----**---**
|| 4 || ... | ... | ... || 2 ||
||   **-----+-----+-----**---**
||   || ... | ... | ... || 3 ||
##===##=====*=====*==========##
||   || ... | ... | ... || 1 ||
||   **-----+-----+-----**---**
|| 5 || ... | ... | ... || 2 ||
||   **-----+-----+-----**---**
||   || ... | ... | ... || 3 ||
##===##=====*=====*=====##===##
```

Where `*` is a single line crossing a double line and `...` are the corresponding `b(n;p;k)`.

I am just asking for a convenient way to format a table like this, there is no need to calculate the binomial probabilities or something like that since this is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve the double line by using `\hhline{#=#===#=#}` as in

[image]

But if you zoom out you'll see some weird details as the one inside the red circle (but visible along the lines):

[image]

But as you would read somewhere else, I'd advise against the use of vertical rules to improve readability. Not to mention that you would have a much cleaner code.

So this is my suggestion for your table. It uses the `booktabs` package which makes for much better lines:

[image]

And the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
        \toprule        
        \multirow{2}{*}{n}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{p} & \multirow{2}{*}{k} \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
                            & .1 & .25 & .5 & \\ \midrule
                            & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 1 \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
                        3   & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 2 \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
                            & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 3 \\ \midrule
                            & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 1 \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
                        4   & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 2 \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
                            & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 3 \\ \midrule
                            & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 1 \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
                        5   & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 2 \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
                            & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 3 \\ \bottomrule

    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since I do not always have 3 rows as in the example (my fault), I needed an additional `\multirow{3}{*}{...}` around the `n` values in the first column. While this works quite nice I noticed that the rules seem to be not included in the multirow heigth (the `n` and `k` in your header row are a little bit too high). With just one rule (like in your header row) this is not a big deal, but with multiple rows it looks weird. Do you have an easy solution or do you think this is worth another question?

Comment: @sg-lecram Well, for the two rows, you could type `\multirow{2}{*}[-2pt]{k}` and the same for `n`... Not sure how to do the centering for multiple rows (I noticed that too) and to be honest, this is the first time I've noticed that. :P